# How to Reduce False Negatives? XGBoost Model with Imbalanced Dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, python, forecasting

I'm participating in a competition of binary classification of disease and I'm using an XGBoost model to classify my data. However, I am experiencing a higher number of false negatives than I would like, leading to bad metric values of the model.

To give you a better understanding, here is part of the preprocessing and modeling code:

```py
def preprocess_data(personal_info_train, measurements_train, personal_info_test, measurements_test):
    # ... data merging, handling missing values, encoding categorical columns, etc. ...

# Training and evaluation function
def train_and_evaluate(training_data, target_labels, categorical_columns):
    preprocessor = make_column_transformer(
        (OneHotEncoder(), categorical_columns),
        remainder='passthrough'
    )

    training_features, validation_features, training_labels, validation_labels = train_test_split(training_data, target_labels, test_size=0.2)
    
    scale_pos_weight = len(training_labels[training_labels == 0]) / len(training_labels[training_labels == 1])

    model_pipeline = make_pipeline(
        preprocessor,
        XGBClassifier(n_jobs=2, learning_rate=0.012, n_estimators=1800, max_depth=14, min_child_weight=2, gamma=0.1, subsample=0.7, colsample_bytree=0.8, reg_lambda=0.8, reg_alpha=0.8, random_state=42, scale_pos_weight=scale_pos_weight)
    )
```

(For the full code, you can refer to my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/BolBoloni/TAUIntro2DS_SolutionModel).)

I've been trying to adjust hyperparameters, but it's not improving the number of false negatives significantly. Given this, I suspect the problem might be related to the data imbalance which I tried to handle using the `scale_pos_weight` parameter.

Here are some performance metrics I've been getting:

| Metric | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Train_AUC | 1 |
| Validation_AUC | 0.980784724 |
| Accuracy | 0.987575243 |
| Precision | 0.910284464 |
| Recall | 0.776119403 |
| F1_Score | 0.837865055 |
| Log_Loss | 0.044203302 |
| MCC | 0.834305991 |
| Balanced_Accuracy | 0.886409404 |
| Confusion_Matrix_TP | 416 |
| Confusion_Matrix_FP | 41 |
| Confusion_Matrix_FN | 120 |
| Confusion_Matrix_TN | 12381 |

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve recall or techniques for reducing false negatives in this scenario?
I tried applying SMOTE to handle class imbalance in my dataset, but it only resulted in worse performance.
Given the data preprocessing steps I've already taken and the unsuccessful application of SMOTE, I'm now seeking alternative methods to improve recall and reduce the number of false negatives. If you've dealt with a similar situation or can share any suggestions, I would really appreciate it!

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: *Especially* (but not only!) in "unbalanced" cases, recall suffers from the exact same problems as accuracy, [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352). It is simply a highly problematic KPI. I understand that you won't be able to have the KPI changed, so the question simply is: what is the target KPI you are judged on? Then use precisely this KPI as a loss function. If you only care about minimizing false negatives, the solution is simple: just classify everything as positive. Zero FN, and you are done. So: what do you want to optimize?

Comment: I second the previous suggestion: do not bother with any fancy modeling like XGBoost and just predict everything to be the positive outcome, guaranteeing perfect recall (yes, perfect recall). If this is problematic, perhaps you can say why.

Comment: To be more clear, the trained model and got a prediction score of 96.5% precent. I want to improve the score and from previous attempts lowering FP and FN numbers improved the final result, so is there any parameter of method to help me achieve this goal? @Dave

Comment: Yes, lowering the number of false negatives and false positives (mistakes) will improve the accuracy. Do you want to improve the accuracy or the recall? Also, have you read the link about why both accuracy and recall are surprisingly problematic?

Comment: @Dave just reading, thank you